# Windows 7 Showing Rectangle Boxes Instead of Characters! [gVim]

Tags: windows-7, windows, vim, fonts, gvim

I have been trying to solve this mystery for such a long time. Within Gvim I see all the airline symbols are not showing. Some are like rectangle boxes. It seems MS Word 2016 can show slightly more characters than gVim.

> gVim - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzeg5.jpg
>
> MS Word 2016 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9gnF.jpg

1. I installed Hack, DejaVu Sans Mono, Iosevka, Fira Code Mono, Input Mono blah blah blah from Github's Nerd fonts & Powerline fonts - no luck
2. Installed Vim Devicons - no luck
3. Opened multiple Issues in Github in Nerd Fonts & Airline pages. Got only one answer. Install a font which has all those glyphs. Even though their recommended fonts never worked!
4. Rebuilt Windows font cache several times - no luck
5. Spent hours on Webchat.freenode IRC - no luck
6. Asked multiple questions in Vim reddit - no luck
7. Here is my .vimrc file... https://pastebin.com/bqrtpzvX
8. Windows 7 64 bit O/S

I guess it is mainly a Windows font problem. All these powerline font's can't fail in this way. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Any guideline will be highly appreciated..

Comment: All those `▯` rectangle boxes are `�` U+FFFD  _Replacement Character_ rendered as a black diamond here (in the current font).[used to replace an unknown, unrecognized or unrepresentable character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character).

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you. But how can I get rid of this problem?